# weights is not changed after applying weights in keras with tensorflow GradientTape

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, tf.keras

The following is the code:

```
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.p_model(obs)
            indices = tf.random.categorical(predictions, 1, dtype=tf.int32)
            indices = tf.squeeze(indices)
            #print('indices:', indices)
            row_indices = tf.range(tf.shape(indices)[0], dtype=tf.int32)
            full_indices = tf.stack([row_indices, indices], axis=1)
            act_val = tf.gather_nd(predictions, full_indices)

            target_preds1 = self.target_model(obs)
            target_preds1 = tf.gather_nd(target_preds1, full_indices)

            target_preds2 = self.target_model2(obs)
            target_preds2 = tf.gather_nd(target_preds2, full_indices)

            target_predict = tf.math.minimum(target_preds1, target_preds2)

            loss_value = self.alpha*tf.math.log(act_val) - target_predict
            loss_value = tf.reduce_mean(loss_value)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.p_model.trainable_weights)
        self.p_optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(grads, self.p_model.trainable_weights))
```

I check grads tensor. It's not zero values. However, trainable_weights is not changed after applying gradients. keras's version is 2.3.1 and tensorflow version is 1.15.0.

I try to enable eager execution, it works. Is it caused by keras or tensorflow version ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. self.p_optimizer.apply_gradients return update_op. Get tf session from keras.back.get_session and run update_op.

```
grads = tape.gradient(final_loss, self.p_model.trainable_weights)
update_op = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.p_model.trainable_weights))
keras.backend.get_session().run(update_op)
```

It works, but it's not necessary to run update_op in normal.